# External HDMI monitor not detected in Ubuntu 18.04 in Dell Inspiron 15 5000 nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

- Tried using proprietary nvidia drivers
- Tried upgrading kernel (Now on 5.3.0)

Ran:
# inxi -Gx

```
    Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 8a52 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1d11 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.6
           drivers: nvidia,fbdev,nouveau (unloaded: modesetting,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@77.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 19.0.8 Direct Render: Yes
```

Ran # xrandr

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

Tried using lightdm, gdm3

Tried using KDE, Mate, and Gnome

No luck, display never detected. Tried 3 different displays too.

Any ideas?

Comment: you could check for EDID. `sudo apt-get install read-edid`. I have a problem where my HDMI monitor returns EDID, but my DVI monitor does not. I use dual screens. so I have to run `xrandr` to config my DVI monitor every time I log into Ubuntu.

Comment: What did you do with the read-edid stuff? Couldn't find any useful info from get-edid or monitor-edid

Comment: `$ sudo get-edid` will scan buses and print 'potential' EDID info from whichever device responds or it will print 'No EDID on bus...'. ref. `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/get-edid.1.html`